# Excel IF statement with range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range `FLrange` which has cells `C3:E10`. I would like to check the value in each cells and if it is zero, need to run formula `SUMIFS(raw!$D:$D,raw!$A:$A,$A3,raw!$C:$C,C$2)`  (This is the formula in cell C3, and other cell has relative formulas)

ie,

C3 : `=SUMIFS(raw!$D:$D,raw!$A:$A,$A3,raw!$C:$C,C$2)`

D3 : `=SUMIFS(raw!$D:$D,raw!$A:$A,$A3,raw!$C:$C,D$2)`

E3 : `=SUMIFS(raw!$D:$D,raw!$A:$A,$A3,raw!$C:$C,E$2)`

C4 : `=SUMIFS(raw!$D:$D,raw!$A:$A,$A4,raw!$C:$C,C$2)`

D5 : `=SUMIFS(raw!$D:$D,raw!$A:$A,$A4,raw!$C:$C,D$2)`

etc....

Note : if you notice above,

In each row, it will change like, C$2, D$2, E$2 at end of formula
In each column, it will change raw!$A:$A,$A3, raw!$A:$A,$A4, raw!$A:$A,$A5 etc

I have tried with below formula

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim FLrange As Range
    Set FLrange = Range("C3:E10")

    For Each cell In FLrange
        If cell.Value = 0 Then cell.Formula = "SUMIFS(raw!$D:$D,raw!$A:$A,$A3,raw!$C:$C,C$2)"
    Next cell
End Sub
```

But, it is loading same formula in all cells, How can I change it to relative one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `R1C1` range format lends itself to this.

Instead of your

```
cell.Formula = "SUMIFS(raw!$D:$D,raw!$A:$A,$A3,raw!$C:$C,C$2)"
```

use

```
cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(raw!C4,raw!C1,R[0]C1,raw!C3,R2C[0])"
```

Note the addition of a `=` in `= "=SUMIFS ...`, necassary to enter it as a formula

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can copy the data from this second sheet to third one ? I specifically need from second..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want a macro to populate the formalae as above.  The macro could be as follows:

```
Sub Macro1()
        Dim FLrange As Range
        Set FLrange = Range("C3:E10")

        For Each cell In FLrange
            If cell.Value = 0 Then
                cell.Formula = "=SUMIFS(raw!$D:$D,raw!$A:$A,$A" & cell.Row & ",raw!$C:$C," _
                & ConvertToLetter(cell.Column) & "$2)"
            End If

        Next cell
End Sub

Function ConvertToLetter(iCol As Integer) As String
   Dim iAlpha As Integer
   Dim iRemainder As Integer
   iAlpha = Int(iCol / 27)
   iRemainder = iCol - (iAlpha * 26)
   If iAlpha > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = Chr(iAlpha + 64)
   End If
   If iRemainder > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = ConvertToLetter & Chr(iRemainder + 64)
   End If
End Function
```

THere may well be a more elegant solution however!